# merge different models with different inputs Keras

Tags: merge, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to train two different Conv models in Keras with different input dimensions.

I have:

```
 input_size=4
 input_sizeB=6

 model=Sequential()
 model.add(Conv2D(filters=10,input_shape= 
 (1,time_steps,input_size),kernel_size(24,3),activation='relu',data_format='channels_first',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
 model.add(Flatten())
A= model.add(Dense(25, 
activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.003)))

 model2=Sequential()
 model2.add(Conv2D(filters=10,input_shape= 
 (1,time_steps,input_sizeB),kernel_size(24,3),activation='relu',data_format='channels_first',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
  model2.add(Flatten())
B= model2.add(Dense(25, 
activation='tanh',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.003)))
```

Now I would merge the two dense layers at the end of both Conv net.

How I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Sequential` API, you can use the `Merge` layer ([doc](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer)) as follows:

```python
merged_layer = Merge([model, model2], mode='concat') # mode='sum', 'ave', etc.
merged_model = Sequential()
merged_model.add(merged_layer)
```

Note that this will throw a warning (depending on your version, the code should still work), as sequential `Merge` is getting deprecated. You could otherwise consider the `Functional` API, which offers some more flexibility in that regards c.f. the several pre-defined *merge* layers Keras provides depending on the operation you want to use ([doc](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)). Find an example below:

```python
merged_layer = Concatenate()([model.output, model2.output])
merged_model = Model([model.input, model2.input], merged_layer)
```

Comment: ok, thank you, but using your code at the end i receive the error: "ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument."

Comment: My bad, I mixed the `Sequential` and `Functional` APIs. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the error is: "The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
  merged = Merge([model, model2,model3], mode='concat') # mode='sum', 'ave', etc.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainValidation_modelAmodelB.py", line 205, in <module>
    merged = Merge([model, model2,model3], mode='concat') # mode='sum', 'ave', etc."

Comment: Depending on your Keras version, this should be only a warning and not an error. As mentioned, you should otherwise consider the `Functional` API. I added an example to my answer if it helps.

Comment: Ok thank. now it works; but the error is (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.

Comment: This is not enough information to help you with this error. I would suggest to create a new question with your new code and inputs.