# Merging Keras models: can Keras automatically ignore names or relabel them?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to merge two sequential models in Keras. The code is as follows, being taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214679/merge-different-models-with-different-inputs-keras):

```
sequential_1 = [keras.layers.Dense(200, input_shape = (784,),activation=tf.nn.relu),
                keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu)] 

model_1 = keras.Sequential(sequential_1)

sequential_2 = [keras.layers.Dense(784, input_shape = (784,), activation=tf.nn.relu),
                keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu)] 

model_2 = keras.Sequential(sequential_1)

collective = Concatenate()([model_1.output, model_2.output])

logits = keras.layers.Dense(10, tf.nn.softmax)(collective) 

combined = Model(inputs = [model_1.input, model_2.input], outputs = [logits])
```

However, I get this error:

```
 The name "dense_4_input" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
```

This is probably coming from the fact that keras automatically names the layers if I don't provide a name. However, for various reasons, I don't want to have have to continually name all my layers before I can merge two models.

Is there a way to merge these models without this error that does not involve manually giving the layer names? Is there a way to have keras automatically rename all the layer names for me?

Update: I still seem to get this error, even if I manually relabel all the layers to have distinct names. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should fully use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) instead of mixing the Sequential and Functional APIs, and then you will not have this problem. Model management and building is much easier with the Functional API as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to mix up `Sequential` and `Functional API`.

If you are going for any model with braches or concatenate then go for `Functional API`.

Your model can be implemented like shown below.

```
i_1 = Input(shape = (784,), name='input_1')
s_1 = Dense(200, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='model_1_dense_1')(i_1)
s_1 = Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='model_1_dense_2')(s_1)

i_2 = Input(shape = (784,), name='input_2')
s_2 = Dense(784, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='model_2_dense_1')(i_1)
s_2 = Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='model_2_dense_2')(s_2)

c = concatenate([s_1, s_2], name='concatenate_layer')

l = Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='logit')(c)

model = Model(inputs = [i_1, i_2], outputs = [l])
```

It is optional to name the layers, Keras will name the layers by default. But to understand things better it is good to name the layers. It will be helpful if you are visualizing the model

Comment: While I understand that in general it is best to use the Functional API for this purpose, in my specific case I am dealing with automatically generated models which come from the sequential API and I want to merge them. That is, I have some large piece of code, and at the end of it I will have a Sequential model returned to me. Unless I rewrite this code, I'm using Sequential. Is there a way to merge the two models that actually would work for the sequential framework.

Comment: Can you convert Sequential model to Functional API with this code https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10386